# from 9 sets of 12 elements, arrange 12 groups of the 9 elements, selecting 1 element from each set

Tags: algorithm, set, combinations

I'm trying to take 9 sets of 12 elements in each set and selecting 1 element from each set to create 12 unique groups.  Now do this 9 times without pairing any 2 elements more than once. The first 12 groups could  be:

1. S1E1   S2E1   S3E1   S4E1   S5E1   S6E1   S7E1   S8E1   S9E1
2. S1E2   S2E2   S3E2   S4E2   S5E2   S6E2   S7E2   S8E2   S9E2
3. S1E3   S2E3   S3E3   S4E3   S5E3   S6E3   S7E3   S8E3   S9E3
4. S1E4   S2E4   S3E4   S4E4   S5E4   S6E4   S7E4   S8E4   S9E4
   .....
5. S1E12  S2E12  S3E12  S4E12  S5E12  S6E12  S7E12  S8E12  S9E12

Second group not too difficult:

1. S1E1   S2E2   S3E3   S4E4   S5E5   S6E6   S7E7   S8E8   S9E9
2. S1E2   S2E3   S3E4   S4E5   S5E6   S6E7   S7E8   S8E9  S9E10
3. S1E3   S2E4   S3E5   S4E6   S5E7   S6E8   S7E9  S8E10  S9E11
4. S1E4   S2E5   S3E6   S4E7   S5E8   S6E9  S7E10  S8E11  S9E12
   .....
5. S1E12   S2E1   S3E2   S4E3   S5E4   S6E5   S7E6   S8E7   S9E8

Now I'm stuck since an arithmetic progression leads to pairing of 2 elements more than once:

1. S1E1   S2E3   S3E5   S4E7   S5E9  S6E11   S7E1(13 mod 12)

Has anyone solved this particular problem?  Arithmetic progression works great for 9 sets of 11 elements and 9 sets of 13 elements (because 11 and 13 are prime numbers?).  Any ideas?

Thanks,
Jim Brown

I tried offsetting the elements each time the progression exceeded 12 and then using modulus but I still end up with duplicate pairs.

Comment: How did you offset? At 12 you need to offset by 1, then if it would have been 24 you need to offset by 2, at 36 by 3, etc. In other words, fake the list 12 items to look like 13.

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it works for that specific grouping of 12 by 9.  But when you build the next grouping, you end up with a pair duplicating a pair from the current grouping, at least if you use the arithmetic progression referred to.

Comment: Of course. I should have thought about it more.

Comment: Jim B. Have you taken this to a math forum?  If not, are you okay with me taking it there?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a bit of a leap here.

The more I look at this, the more I think it is actually mathematically impossible.

The solution for 9 sets of 12 elements, with elements grouped into 108 sets of 9 elements with no pairing of elements in any set repeated is that there is no solution.

I would conjecture that in general for s sets of e elements with elements grouped into s x e sets of s elements with no pairing of elements in any set repeated is only doable if e is prime and s <= e. Mutual primality between s and e is not sufficient.

But I could be wrong.

You may wish to take the problem to the math forum ...

[EDIT 20221109] Correction to conjecture: e must be prime.